# How to share DbContexts and not get 2 user tables

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using Asp.Net Core 3.1 with Entity Framework, Asp.Net Identity, and IdentityServer4. I'm trying to share my DbContexts across several projects but my code first migrations aren't producing what I need. Is this possible with code first migrations? Is my setup completely asinine? Thank you for your time.

---

### My project hierarchy with DbContexts.

[image: Project Heirarchy]

### What I want

[image: Entity Relationship Goal]

### What I get

[image: Entity Relationship Actual]

### In both Identity and Application Startups

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppUserContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
...
services.AddDbContext<AppUserContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

### Migrations

```
dotnet-ef migrations add Init -p User\User.csproj -c AppUserContext -s IdentityServer\IdentityServer.csproj
dotnet-ef migrations add Init -p Persistence\Persistence.csproj -c RecipeContext -s Application\Application.csproj
```

---

### Update 1

Moving AppUser and AppUserContext to IdentityServer. Red is a restricted endpoint.

[image: Update 1 Sequence]

Comment: The question is not clear to me - you introduce an AppUser yourself.

Comment: You should reconsider your design. Keep AspNetUser in the Identity context and don't mix it with other contexts. Especially when using IdentityServer. No application should have access to this context for security reasons. You can use the value of the UserId, but don't create database relations that are across contexts. Keep the tables and relations within its context. It'll make things easier.

Comment: @HenkHolterman both AspNetUser and AppUser tables are created by migrating the AppUser class. However in the first case it uses Asp.Net Identity and in the second it doesn't (or that is at least what it seems). My original goal was to have both migrations use Asp.Net Identity's AspNetUser table.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg that does simplify things. In that paradigm how do I create new users? Application has a /user/register endpoint that calls a user/register endpoint on IdentityServer that is restricted to my Application server? I would also need a user entity in Application (ie: Chef) which would as you say have a UserID but no relation to the UserContext.

Comment: Added an update to the post to include a sequence diagram of what that flow would possibly look like.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I went with your suggestion and have a working solution thank you. Do you want to answer this question so I can select it and give you points?

Comment: @StephenYeager Thank you for asking, but it was only a suggestion, not an answer to your question. If you like, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RuardvanElburg's advice, I "solved" this by changing my paradigm which you can see in my **Update 1**.